# How to Nested Categories in django admin

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I want to create muti category in my ecommerce website where sub category will be dependent on main category.
Please help me with this

```
 class MainCategory(models.Model):
#     name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
#     date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

#     def __str__(self):
#         return self.name

# class SubCategory(models.Model):
#     perentcategory = models.OneToOneField(MainCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True) 
#     name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
#     date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

#     def __str__(self):
#         return self.name


# class Items(models.Model):
#     main = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
#     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Posting this question 4th time

Comment: You’ve not asked a question. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: I want to create dynamic nested category models so when admin add new product It will show 1st main category and then admin will have option to select sub category

Answer (score 0):

Change `models.OneToOneField` to `models.ForeignKey` so you can have multiple subcategories assigned to a main category:

```
class MainCategory(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.name

 class SubCategory(models.Model):
     main_category = models.ForeignKey(MainCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True) 
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.name


 class Items(models.Model):
     main = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering

but I want to also admin to select first main then its relevant category will show in product add

Comment: Hi. Did it answer your question? If not, I can amend my answer if you can share more details about the problem.

Comment: I want to create nested categories so when I sub category I will select perent main category its working as your solve this above

but I also want that when I add product I want to select main category first then sub category will be show based on main category

In your solution I can only select sub category but I also want to select main in Product add

Comment: Are you using the django admin?

Comment: You'll have to set a custom form for your ModelAdmin, then add JS files to the admin page so the subcategory dropdown updates when the main category dropdown changes. 

If you are fine with a two step process, where you select the main category, then save, then select the subcategory, then save again, you can add a main category field to the model, and filter the subcategory form field in the `ModelAdmin.form` based on the instance's main category field.

If you get what I'm saying and prefer one of these solution, I can guide you to the right resources, but this is not a trivial task.

Comment: thanks for your help  sir 
can you suggest me that that should I create a new app for custom admin panel for website or I just need to create front end and backend in same app?

Comment: So I use models to create admin panel and I doing right thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use single model to accommodate both Category and Sub-categories. Something like this.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',blank=True, null=True ,related_name='children', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Then add following function to the above model

```
def get_categories(self):
         if self.parent is None:
              return self.name
         else:
             return self.parent.get_categories() + ' -> ' + self.name
    
def __str__(self):
        return self.get_categories()
```

This will return structure similar to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJune.jpg)